# Refresh the DetailiInit in Kendo Grid Jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

How to Refresh only detailInit in kendo grid without refreshing parent grid or want to expand the parent grid to that row at which i have perform some operation

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#ChildGridId').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
$('#ChildGridId').data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```